# Is it normal for some values in a heatmap to appear darker than they should be?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

so i have that some value(the lower one) in the heatmap matrix should not be that dark, but still they are.
check the image at the end

```
categories = list(dictionary.label2idx.keys())


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

target_tokens_flat = np.array([label for sentence_labels in target_tokens for label in sentence_labels])
output_tokens_flat = np.array([label for sentence_labels in output_tokens for label in sentence_labels])
print(target_tokens_flat)

cm = confusion_matrix(target_tokens_flat, output_tokens_flat, labels=categories)
print(cm)

fmt = '.2%'
total_predictions = np.sum(cm)
annot = np.empty_like(cm).astype(str)
cm = np.array(cm)


column_sums = [np.sum(cm[:, i], axis=0) for i in range(cm.shape[0])]
print(column_sums)
result = [(cm[:, i] / (column_sums[i]+0.0000001)).round(4) for i in range(cm.shape[1])]


result = np.transpose(result)
print(result)

sns.heatmap(cm, annot=result, fmt=fmt, cmap='flare', xticklabels=categories, yticklabels=categories,vmin=0, vmax=100)
```

this is the result:

[image: Confusion matrix with labels]
In the first column, why 0.44% is so dark?

These are the print outputs:

```
['O' 'O' 'O' ... 'O' 'O' 'O']
[[31041   522   208   206    26    52     1    12     6     0     0]
 [  395  1284    41    20     3    11     0     0     0     0     0]
 [  140    47   796     9     8     2     0     0     0     0     0]
 [  111     9    12   367     3     0     0     0     0     0     0]
 [   33    14     6     2   138     4     0     0     0     0     0]
 [   43    28     7     2     3   132     0     0     0     0     0]
 [    3     0     0     0     0     0    33     3     0     0     0]
 [   16     5     0     0     0     0     2    11     0     0     0]
 [   10     0     0     0     0     0     0     1    41     0     0]
 [    0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0]
 [    1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0]]
[31793, 1909, 1070, 606, 181, 201, 36, 28, 47, 0, 0]
[[9.763e-01 2.734e-01 1.944e-01 3.399e-01 1.436e-01 2.587e-01 2.780e-02
  4.286e-01 1.277e-01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [1.240e-02 6.726e-01 3.830e-02 3.300e-02 1.660e-02 5.470e-02 0.000e+00
  0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 ....
 [3.000e-04 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00
  3.570e-02 8.723e-01 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00
  0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]
 [0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00
  3.570e-02 0.000e+00 0.000e+00 0.000e+00]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still using the unnormalized (per column) `cm` for your heatmap. Use the normalized `result` instead. Set `vmax` accordingly to `1` as well.

```
sns.heatmap(result, annot=result, fmt=fmt, cmap='flare', 
            xticklabels=categories, yticklabels=categories,vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

yields
[image]

(If you want `100%` for the colorbar, you'll probably need to do some manual tweaking for that. `cbar_kws` may help with that; e.g., use `format` to specify another formatter, or set the tick labels manually).